# Adding Line Out / Sub Out to LG soundbar

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, amplifier, circuit-design, dsp

I have LG Soundbar with wireless sub. I am trying to add Line output, so i could connect a wired sub.
I took some pictures of the boards and chips. If someone could point me in right direction on where to connect to get low level output. My second option is to add High to low converter but that doesn't always provide clean signal.
ps9860 is Multi-channel Digital Audio Processor Eight-channels i think that should be where i could get a connection. If someone could confirm I'd appreciate it.
StackExchange only allowed me to upload one photo, so I'm attaching link to folder with more photos.
https://fil.email/BeJMkJMl

Comment: Anyone able to assist on this? I would really appreciate it.